# Windows10 Python Program Disappear

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a py file called simplifier. Usually when you double click the py file, Windows should give you both a console and the program. Just like the picture below.

[image]

However, I clicked my py file and the console showed up and disappeared in a flash and the program did not show up at all. Usually this means there should be some bugs in my code. So I opened the py file in IDLE and ran it, expecting the shell to give me an error. However, it did not report anything. I don't know how to locate the error. The file used to work well and it just started to behave like that. I tested putting "input('')" only in a py file and it worked as expected. And some of my programs also work well, but the rest doesn't.

Could the bug come from my imported modules? I import some module written by myself (ez and eztk). I checked those functions. They are ok.

Here is the code of simplifier.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from eztk import *
import ez

root=Tk()
root['bg']='MintCream'
t1=Text(root)
def newline():
    t=gettxt(t1)
    new=''
    for i,ch in enumerate(t):
        if ch=='\n' and t[i+1:i+3]!='- ':
            new+=' '
        else:
            new+=ch
    inst2(new)
w0=Label(root,text='Input:↑')
w1=Button(root,text="\\n",command=newline)
def brackets():
    t=gettxt(t1)
    new=''
    stop=0
    d={'[':']','(':')','{':'}',0:None}
    for ch in t:
        if ch in d:
            stop=ch
        elif ch==d[stop]:
            stop=0
        elif not stop:
            new+=ch
    inst2(new)
w2=Button(root,text='([{}])',command=brackets)
def linecount(event):
    count=lambda t:t.count('\n')+(t[-1]!='\n') if t else 0
    up=count(gettxt(t1))
    down=count(gettxt(t2))
    w3['text']=f'LineCount:↑{up}↓{down}'
root.bind('<KeyPress>', linecount)
w3=Label(root,text='LineCount')
def clear():
    deltxt(t1)
    deltxt(t2)
w4=Button(root,text='Clear',command=clear)
t2=Text(root)

ws=[w0,w1,w2,w3,w4]
t1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=len(ws))
for i,w in enumerate(ws):
    w.configure(relief=FLAT,bg='SeaGreen1')
    w.grid(row=1,column=i,sticky=NS)
t2.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=len(ws))

def inst2(text):
    deltxt(t2)
    instxt(t2,text)
    linecount('<KeyPress>')
    try: ez.cpc(text)
    except UnicodeError: messagebox.showerror('Error','You need to copy it to your clipboard manually.')

root.mainloop()
```

These are the functions used in the imported modules:

```
def copyToClipboard(text):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(text)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
## abbreviation
cpc=copyToClipboard

def gettxt(text):
    return text.get(1.0,'end').strip()

def deltxt(text):
    text.delete(1.0,'end')

def instxt(textwidget,text):
    textwidget.insert(1.0,text)
```

--- Update ---

I just tried copy the 4 functions to the simplifier.py instead of importing them, it worked. However, I also tried importing either of them and both cases failed. And there is still no error after I ran them in the python shell. Actually the bottom 3 functions are the only code in my eztk module. And it still doesn't work as expected when I import eztk alone, which means there shouldn't be any problems with importing.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a [mcve] to your question so people can help you with your problem. As it stands, there is no code to help you with. Also, you say that there are imported modules - so show us some of the code in the library so we can help.

Comment: @Jono2906 Hi Jono, thank you for your speedy response. I have updated my question, could you please check it out?

Comment: I recommend that you upload the program as text onto the post instead of an image: questions containing pictures containing code tend to attract downvotes.

Comment: @Jono2906 Hi, I have modified my question.

Comment: Having a look at it now

Comment: TBH, I have the same problems as well on my computer!

Comment: @Jono2906 I noticed a weird thing. I stopped importing my modules and copied the 4 functions to the simplifier.py. It worked. The bottom 3 functions are actually the only code of my eztk module. I don't think there should be any problems with importing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167007/discussion-between-jono-2906-and-seaky-lone).